# API - Convert Bitcoin Amount into USD with my Api

Tags: php, json

After `apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com` is not free anymore i need an other solution.

I want convert an `x BTC Amount` into USD from current rate.

**My Old Code:**

```
$getrate = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/convert/global?from=BTC&to=USD&amount=0.005";
$btcprice = array(
  'price' =>
    array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    )
);
$priceone = stream_context_create($btcprice);
$pricetwo = file_get_contents($getrate, false, $priceone);
$result = json_decode($pricetwo, true);
```

Can i do the same with api from https://alternative.me/crypto/api/ ?

Many Thanks

Comment: the documentation shows `https://api.alternative.me/v2/ticker/?convert=USD` which returns the USD value for different coinst (BTC, ETH, XRP etc.) you can then retrieve the value you need from the returned json.

Comment: Yes but i dont know how i can convert the `0.005` in USD, any ideas?

Comment: The `0.005` being the amount of currency to convert, I guess you'd multiply the retrieved price by `0.005`...

Comment: Oh yes thats works :) but how can i get the current usd price from array with `https://api.alternative.me/v2/ticker/?convert=USD` sorry very new to php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do following, according to the [documentation](https://alternative.me/crypto/api/):

```
<?php
$getrate = "https://api.alternative.me/v2/ticker/?convert=USD";

$price = file_get_contents($getrate);
$result = json_decode($price, true);

// BTC in USD
$result = $result['data'][1]['quotes']['USD']['price'];

$quantity = 0.005;
$value = $quantity * $result;
echo 'value : ' . $value;
```

**note**(thx @AndreasHassing): if you only want Bitcoin data in the json response, use:

`$getrate = "https://api.alternative.me/v2/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=USD";`

Comment: I got the error: PHP Fatal error:  `Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in Main.php:11 for line $value = $quantity * $result;` but you helped me a lot thanks:)

Comment: @tonnylaf consider using the following URL instead (if you only care about Bitcoin): https://api.alternative.me/v2/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=USD as it reduces the amount of data returned to only data relevant to Bitcoin. It causes less wait time for you, and less strain in the free API on which you depend :-)